# Excel VBA is not recording macro properly

Tags: excel, vba

Had some troubles while recording macro on my Excel. I followed some tutorials on youtube but I still did fail to record and then execute Macro properly.
Here's an example: when I am recording the action of selecting one interval, it should be ends up with something like that in the VBA editor: Range("C3:E7").Select; instead, in the VBA editor I find Range("C3:E7").DataFields, which obviously doesnt work when executed.

Similarly, when I try to record the action of calculating an average from an interval, it ends up with some awkard code like
Bold. = "=AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-1]:R[1]C[-1])"

What am I miss? is there something I didnt get?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Excel?

Answer (score 2):

The "awkward code" is a formula in R1C1 notation. This is the easiest way to create formulas with relative references in VBA.

The macro recorder is not a perfect tool. Many things that run fine while recording a macro will not run when the recorded macro is played back. Also, there are some activities that the macro recorder does not register at all. In these cases you need to consult the VBA documentation and correct the code manually.

Your code snippet about the Range Select lacks a lot of detail to determine what went wrong. Without seeing your data and knowing more about your exact steps, it will not be possible to troubleshoot.

Comment: I simply activate the recorder button, selected one interval of cells with mouse, and then stop the recorder.
where did I go wrong?

I think it may be some kind of settings of how the recorder reads and write my actions...

Comment: I don't know what an "interval" of cells is. If you mean a range, i.e. several cells in a row and/or column, then the resulting code will depend on what exactly is in that range. if the code returns `DataFields` , then you selected something in a PivotTable, which is not the same as selecting ordinary cells.